# How can I feed a string to awk for the purpose of mathematical calculation?

Tags: awk, posix, math

```
#!/bin/sh --

expression_to_evaluate='12 + 3'

printf '%s\n' "Arithemtic Expansion: $(( $expression_to_evaluate ))"

printf '%s' 'bc: '
printf '%s\n' "$expression_to_evaluate" | bc

printf '%s' 'awk: '
awk -v expression_to_evaluate="$expression_to_evaluate" -- 'BEGIN{printf "%d\n", expression_to_evaluate}'
```

Output:

```
Arithemtic Expansion: 15
bc: 15
awk: 12
```

`awk` is returning 12 instead of 15. How can I feed a string to `awk` for the purpose of mathematical calculation?

Comment: Should it also be able to handle expressions like `1 + system("date +%s")` or `++var` or `++a[1]` or `ENVIRON["SHLVL"] + 3`. In other words, how do you define *mathematical calculation*?

Comment: you can use the `eval()` function in gawk.  I have a few examples in my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, `eval()` is a function I wrote.  I explain how the function works and how to use it below.

Answer (score 2):

While this works, I recommend against it because, unless you control the source of `expression_to_evaluate`, it is a security risk:

```
$ expression_to_evaluate='12 + 3'
$ awk "BEGIN{printf \"%d\n\", $expression_to_evaluate}"
15
```

Comment: Note that `echo "$(($expression_to_evaluate))"` is also an arbitrary command injection vulnerability in bash/ksh/zsh, and even in `dash` or `yash` can be abused to set sensitive variables like PATH or IFS. But the OP is more or less asking for arbitrary code to be evaluated here.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` does not have a way to evaluate a general arithmetic expression given to it as a string.  `bc`, on the other hand, takes an expression and evaluates it, as does the shell.

Would you want to evaluate the string as a mathematical expression in `awk`, you would either have to inject the expression as *code* into the `awk` program (potentially creating a code injection vulnerability), or simply write your own parser for the types of expressions you'd like to evaluate (this is a common computer science homework assignment).

You get `12` from your `awk` code because the value of `expression_to_evaluate`, when converted into an integer, can be converted up until the space character in the string.  This is how the `strtol()` C library function works when it converts a string into an integer, and `awk` is likely using this under the hood.

Comment: _"You would either have to inject the expression as code"_. How is that different from `bc`? `bc` can't even take external input, all you can do is inject code to it.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The difference is that it's the normal mode of operation for `bc` to read expressions from standard input. It is not the normal mode of operation of `awk` to insert shell code (user input) into the string that serves as the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I forgot that I wrote this function a long time ago and have it automatically imported into awk.

The eval function has the following code:

```
function eval(str,cmd,line,ret) {
    cmd = "gawk \047BEGIN{print " str "; exit}\047"
    if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        ret = line
    }
    close(cmd)
    return ret
}
```

if you put this in a file, you can import it before your script using

```
awk -i fileWithFunction.awk '{print eval($1)}'
```

I have awk as a function so I never need to think about importing functions that I use regularly.

```
awk () {
    awk -i awk_functions.awk "$@"
}
```

I apologize for the confusion!

**ORIGINAL POST**

the `eval()` (note, you have to import this function from a file, or put it into your awk script!  See above.) function in awk will do what you want.  This might be gawk specific, but if you aren't using `gawk` then you should be anyways :)

**Example**

```
$ expression="1+1"
$ echo | awk -v expression=$expression '{print eval(expression)}'
2

$ expression="2^10"
$ echo | awk -v expression=$expression '{print eval(expression)}'
1024
```

You can also make a simple awk program input to take typed in values and process them

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printf "Expression:"}{print eval($0);printf "Expression:"}'
Expression:2^29
536870912
Expression: log(10)/log(30)
0.676992
Expression: I love cake
```

Comment: GNU `awk` does not, as far as I know, have `eval()`. It is unclear what `awk` you are using.  If it's GNU `awk`, then `eval` is not used as a function (unless that has changed in whatever version of the utility).

Comment: @Kusalananda You are right!  I had forgotten I wrote this function and import it automatically.  The answer is correct once you take that into account.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $expression_to_evaluate | awk -F "+" '{print ($1+$2)}'
```

Comment: They didn't ask for static addition, they asked `How can I feed a string to awk for the purpose of mathematical calculation?`